# Loop through JSON array in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have an external JSON file that has this in it:

```
{
"Home": [
    { "link":"index.php" , "text":"Home" }, 
    { "link":"index.php?page=aboutus" , "text":"About Us" }
]
"Games": [
    { "link":"games.php" , "text":"All Games" }, 
    { "link":"games.php?name=game" , "text":"Game" }
]
}
```

That is the basic setup of my JSON file. I plan on adding more as my site expands. I am using that as part of my menu bar setup. It has 3 buttons, Home, Games, and Forum. When you mouse over the Home button I want to turn the stuff in "Home" into links and show it up on my site, same with the Games button, nothing is going to show up when you mouse over the Forum button. I have tried this:

Edit: changed the function slightly again, trying to keep it from calling the server on each mouse over, as well as loop through them all and show them in the .navDD div tag.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var menu
    $.getJSON('menu.json', function(data) {
        menu = data;
    });
    $(".navlink").mouseenter(function(){
        var find=$(this).text();
        $.each(data,function(index){
            $(".navDD").html(menu[find][index]['text']);
        });
    });
});
```

I am sure I mess something up still. Now I getUncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined. I am not sure at all what I am doing wrong. Though I have never worked with JSON before this.

Could someone please help me?

Thanks,
Legobear154

Comment: Are you even getting into the callback function of `$.getJSON()`?

Comment: Do you have `http://example.com/menu.json` or whatever on your webserver?

Comment: @MarcB - he must, if he's getting the error he describes

Comment: if you are positive that the `text` of the home button is `Home` exact spelling, then `$(".navDD").html(data[find][0]['text']);` will work. If you are still not getting it then log it to the console. in chrome, `console.log(data[find][0]['text']);`

Comment: I edited main post with new code. Still get an error though, as stated above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try doing it this way:

```
$(".navlink").mouseenter(function(){
    var find=$(this).text;
    $.getJSON('menu.json', function(data) {
        $(".navDD").html(data[find][0].text);
    });
});
```

Access a property via it's name. This is assuming that the text value you are using matches the JSON property of your object.

I would also suggest not doing the `$.getJSON()` on every mouse enter. That is a lot of server traffic. Users could be "mouse entering" hundreds of times.

Comment: i think that you are right but he is making an error before that `$(this).text` should be `$(this).text()`

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that this is correct?

```
 var find=$(this).text;
```

I'd do:

```
 var find=$(this).text();
```

And then

```
   $.getJSON('menu.json', function(data) {
        $(".navDD").html(data.[find][0].text);
    });
```

Comment: See first post for modifications

Answer (score 0):

There is no `find` property in your object, so that's giving you `undefined`.  You're then trying to read the 0th index of this undefined property, which is giving you the error.

If you want to access the the text property of the 0th element in the home object, you would say `data.home[0].text`

Comment: Or to be even more obvious, `data["home"][0]["text"]`

Comment: @Andrew That would work too - I prefer using the "dot" to navigate through, but that's just my preference.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var key in data) {
    if (key == 'Home'){
        $(".navDD").html(data[key]['text']);
    }
}
```

you should also make sure that you are working with an object when using for loops. That might be where your 'undefined' error is coming from.

```
if (typeof data === 'object'){
    for (var key in data) {
        if (key == 'Home'){
            $(".navDD").html(data[key]['text']);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `var find=$(this).text` to get the content of the element, you need to use `var find=$(this).text()` to call the `text` method.

You are using `data.find[0].text` to get a value from the object, you need to use `menuData[find][0].text`.

You should not request the JSON file every time the `mouseenter` event happens, you should only request it the first time, then hold on to it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var menuData = null;

  $(".navlink").mouseenter(function(){
    var find = $(this).text();
    if (menuData != null) {
      $(".navDD").text(menuData[find][0].text);
    } else {
      $.getJSON('menu.json', function(data) {
        menuData = data;
        $(".navDD").text(menuData[find][0].text);
      });
    }
  });

});
```